# proof of immersion theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

> Definition: Let A be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $f: A \to \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ a $C^{1}$ function. Given $x_{0} \in A$, f is immersion at $x_{0}$ if $Df(x_{0})$ is injective.
>
> theorem: Let $A$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $f: A \to \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ ($k > 0$) a $C^{1}$ map. Consider fixed $x_{0} \in A$. If $f$ is an immersion at $x_{0}$, then exists an open subset $U \subset A$ such that $x_{0} \in U$ and $f(U)$ is a graphic of a $C^{1}$, $g: V \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$, where $V$ is open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
>
> proof:

Consider $Df(x_{0})$ the differential operator that is injective by hypothesis. Let $Jf(x_{0})$ the Jacobian matrix associated to $f$,

$Jf(x_{0}) = $
$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{1}}(x_{0}) & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{n}}(x_{0})\\ 
\vdots &  & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial f_{n+k}}{\partial x_{1}}(x_{0}) & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_{n+k}}{\partial x_{n}}(x_{0})
\end{pmatrix}
$

Observe that the rows of this matrix can be considered as a vector of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Using linear algebra, we have n linear independent rows (or vectors) in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Thus, we can isolate these rows to form a square matrix with determinant different of zero.

**Case 1**

Suppose these rows are first n. Consider the cannonic isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{k}$. Then, we can write $f(x) = (v(x), w(x))$, where $v: A \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $w: A \to \mathbb{R}^{k}$. By the hypothesis of case 1, $Dv(x_{0}): \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an isomorphism.

Now, we can apply the theorem of inverse function, so there are open subsets $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $x_{0} \in U$ ($U \subset A$) and $V \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $v(x_{0}) \in V$, such that the restriction of $v$ to $U$, $v: U \to V$, is a $C^{1}$ function, bijective, and the inverse is $C^{1}$.

We still need to find the function $g$, consider
$$g: V \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$$
where $g(y) = w(v^{-1}(y))$.

Observe that the image of f restrict to $U$ is
$$f(U) = \{(v(x), w(x)) : x \in U\}$$
and the graphic of g is

$$G(G) = \{(y, g(y)) : y \in V\}$$

like $y = v(x), x \in U$ and $g(y) = w(v^{-1}(y)) = w(x), x \in U$, we conclude that $f(U) = G(g)$.

**Case 2:**

Consider that in the matrix $Jf(x_{0})$ the rows $e_{j_{1}}, \cdots, e_{j_{n}}$ are linearly independent, where $i \to j_{i}$ is a increasing injective function of $\{1, \cdots, n\}$ to $\{1, \cdots, n+k \}$.

Now, observe that we can change the rows of the matrix $Jf(x_{0})$ using elementary matrices. How this kind of matrix has determinant different of zero, the product of elementary matrices has determinant different of zero, and therefore this product can be associated with an isomorphism $T: \mathbb{R}^{n+k} \to \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$.

Defined, $F = T\circ f : A \to \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$, thus we have that $DF(x_{0}) = DT(f(x_{0})) \circ Df(x_{0})$ is injective. Hence, we can use the case 1 with respect to $F$.
Lastly, we need find a function $g$ such that $f(U) = G(g)$, but i can find it!

Someone can help to finish this prove, only remains find the function g.

Thank you in advance